# Sharepoint 2010 Custom Coreresultswebpart doesnt show message "No results..." when no results

Tags: 2010, web-part, search

I have created a custom Coreresultswebpart but it doesn't show the default message when no search results are returned from the users search. The OOB Coreresultswebpart shows a message like: 
"your search for "hello" didn't returned any results.bla bla try to search"

I am sure that is not beacause of the xslt, because i am using the standard xslt.

Answer (score 1):

You may be sure, but I would still suspect the XSL. There is a line that evaluates a variable in the XSL that determines if there are any results. If there aren't it displays the No Results Template (dvt_1.empty) and the no results variable text.

The XSL injects a bunch of divs and spans. Are you using a custom CSS that may be the root of the issue?

Comment: if you tick the checkbox UseLocationVisualization the original xsl is used, so the xsl is not the problem. No custom css.

Comment: Right, but he's using a custom web part.

Comment: if you edit the Coreresultswebpart no mather if it is a custom one or the OOB, there is a property that the user can set 
"use location visualization" and that one resets the xsl to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Check the webpart properties, as I believe the Out of the box webparts allow you to specify this text or at least tick a checkbox to enable or disable the display of this "no results" text. Your custom wp may be lacking this.

Comment: can't find such property.. i thought that showMessages maybe was the property. But no help.